# Deciding whether DCFG is visibly pushdown

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, context-free

Is the following problem decidable?
If so, what's the best algorithm known?

> **Instance:** a deterministic pushdown automaton $A$
> **Question:** Does there exist (i) some partition of the alphabet into push, pop, and level symbols and (ii) a visibly pushdown automaton that recognizes the language accepted by $A$?

Comment: Due to the decidability of DPDA equivalence one 'merely' has to show there exist *some* (no matter how bad) computable function $f(n)$ upper-bounding the sufficient size of a VPDA for $L(A)$ given DPDA $A$ of size $n$, as we can then simply enumerate them.

Comment: And regardless this immediately shows the problem is at least semi-decidable.